# How to change vertical <tr> into horizontal <tr>

Tags: javascript

This code produced to do 2 things. First one is to highlight table record when checkbox is clicked. Second one is to remeber the result even page is refreshed.

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <style>
    .highlight-red {
        background-color: red;
    }    
    .highlight-green {
        background-color: green;
    }
    .highlight-yellow {
        background-color: yellow;
    }    
    </style>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <table id="Table" border="1" >
            <tr class="highlight">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1" value="y" onChange="changeSoma(this, 'red')" /></td>
            <td>Click me</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb2" id="cb2" value="y" onChange="changeSoma(this, 'green')" /></td>
            <td>Click me</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb3" id="cb3" value="y" onChange="changeSoma(this, 'yellow')" /></td>
            <td>Click me</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        function changeSoma(data, color){
                if(data.checked && color == 'red'){
                    $(data).parent().parent().addClass("highlight-red");
                }
                else{
                    $(data).parent().parent().removeClass("highlight-red");
                }
                if(data.checked && color == 'green'){
                    $(data).parent().parent().addClass("highlight-green");
                }
                else{
                    $(data).parent().parent().removeClass("highlight-green");
                }
                if(data.checked && color == 'yellow'){
                    $(data).parent().parent().addClass("highlight-yellow");
                }
                else{
                    $(data).parent().parent().removeClass("highlight-yellow");
                }
        }
    </script>
    <script>

        var cond = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("check"));
        for(var i in cond) {
            if(cond[i]) {
             $("#"+i).attr("checked",true);
             $("#"+i).parent().parent().addClass("highlight-"+cond[i]);
            }
        }
        function changeSoma(data, color){
                var state;
                if(localStorage.getItem("check") == null) {
                    state = {cb1:0,cb2:0,cb3:0};
                } else{
                    state = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("check"));
                }

                if(data.checked) {
                    $(data).parent().parent().addClass("highlight-"+color);
                    state[data.id]= color;
                } else {
                    $(data).parent().parent().removeClass("highlight-"+color);
                    state[data.id]= 0;
                }
                localStorage.setItem("check",JSON.stringify(state));
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

But I need three checkboxes to be horizontal. When I remove tr tags, only one colors highlight all three check boxes, Other 2 colors doesn't work.It is shown below. How Can I change this? Ca anybody explain me where is my bug?
[image]

Comment: One `<tr>` with 6 `<td>` ?

Comment: Yes. one table row can have many table data. Isn't that so?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite getting what you're trying to do. Did you mean you want the same functionality but with everything in one row?

Comment: Yes Mr.Braedan. I need three check boxes to be horizontal. They should have 3 separate colors to be higligted when they are clicked and their results should stay same even page refresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add this to your tr tag. No need for deleting it.

```
style="display: inline-block;"
```

Should look like this

```
<tr style="display: inline-block;">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1" value="y" onChange="changeSoma(this, 'red')" /></td>
    <td>Click me</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Mr.Jack Mov this is the coolest option.Thank you soooooooo much

Comment: Good call, would have never thought of that. Sometimes the simplest solution is the best I guess haha

Comment: Dushee, no problem. And @Weedoze offered a shorter and nicer js code.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function changeSoma(data, color) {
  if (data.checked)
    $(data).parent().addClass(`highlight-${color}`);
  else
    $(data).parent().removeClass(`highlight-${color}`);
}
```

```css
.highlight-red {
  background-color: red;
}

.highlight-green {
  background-color: green;
}

.highlight-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-10">
  <table id="Table" border="1">
    <tr class="highlight">
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1" value="y" onChange="changeSoma(this, 'red')"/></td>
      <td>Click me</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb2" id="cb2" value="y" onChange="changeSoma(this, 'green')" /></td>
      <td>Click me</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb3" id="cb3" value="y" onChange="changeSoma(this, 'yellow')" /></td>
      <td>Click me</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost the same as above, but targets the text `td` rather than the checkboxes

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <table id="Table" border="1">
        <tr class="highlight">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1" value="y" onChange="changeSoma(this, 'red')" /></td>
            <td class="red">Click me</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb2" id="cb2" value="y" onChange="changeSoma(this, 'green')" /></td>
            <td class="green">Click me</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb3" id="cb3" value="y" onChange="changeSoma(this, 'yellow')" /></td>
            <td class="yellow">Click me</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
    function changeSoma(data, color) {
        if (data.checked)
            $("." + color + "").addClass(`highlight-${color}`);
        else
            $("." + color + "").removeClass(`highlight-${color}`);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Dushee If you want to highlight the checkboxes as well, just add the colour class to the `td`

Comment: Thank you Mr.Braeden. Stackoverflow community is awesome. Today I learnt so many approaches where I can go.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap all your `<td>` elements into a single `<tr>` so they'd all appear in a single row. I'd also suggest to wrap your text into a `<label>` so you can identify your `<label>` and the corresponding `<input>` in order to just style their parent `<td>` elements.

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
  <table id="Table" border="1">
    <tr class="highlight">
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1" value="y" onChange="changeSoma(this, 'red')" />
        </td>
        <td>Click me</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb2" id="cb2" value="y" onChange="changeSoma(this, 'green')" />
      </td>
      <td>Click me</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb3" id="cb3" value="y" onChange="changeSoma(this, 'yellow')" />
      </td>
      <td>Click me</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

JS (only your if block)

```
  if (data.checked) {
    $(data).parent().parent().addClass("highlight-" + color);
    state[data.id] = color;
  } else {
    $(data).parent().parent().removeClass("highlight-" + color);
    state[data.id] = 0;
  }
  localStorage.setItem("check", JSON.stringify(state));
}
```

[Live demo](https://codepen.io/Aer0/pen/EvVRrV?editors=1011)